# Find a value of $n$ such that the coefficients of $x^7$ and $x^8$ are in the expansion of $\displaystyle \left(2+\frac{x}{3}\right)^{n}$ are equal

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> > Question: Find a value of $n$ such that the coefficients of $x^7$ and $x^8$ are in the expansion of $\displaystyle \left(2+\frac{x}{3}\right)^{n}$ are equal.

---

My attempt:

$\displaystyle \binom{n}{7}=\binom{n}{8} $

$$ n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6) \times 2^{n-7} \times (\frac{1}{3})^7= n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)(n-7) \times 2^{n-8} \times (\frac{1}{3})^8 $$

$$ \frac{6}{7!} = \frac{n-7}{40320} $$

$$ n-7 = 48 $$

$$ n=55 $$

Comment: If $$\binom{n}{7}=\binom{n}{8} $$ then $n=7+8=15$

Comment: Do any $n$ between $0$ and $6$ count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^7$ is
$$\binom{n}{7}\frac{2^{n-7}}{3^7}$$
And the coefficient of $x^8$ is
$$\binom{n}{8}\frac{2^{n-8}}{3^8}$$
Comparing them we get:
$$\binom{n}{8}=\binom{n}{7}\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The general term of $(a+b)^n$ $$t_{r+1}={n\choose r}.a^r.b^{n-r}$$  plug in r as $6,7$ and you will get it

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $x^7$ will be ${n\choose 7}{2^{n-7}\over 3^7}$ and the coefficient of $x^8$ will be ${n\choose 8}{2^{n-8}\over 3^8}$ and not what you have got .you just missed out the factor of 3 that plays a role as a coefficient.So equating it you get
$${n\choose 7}{2^{n-7}\over 3^7}={n\choose 8}{2^{n-8}\over 3^8}$$
and get the answer as $55$

Answer (score 1):

Reference that $$(a + b)^n = {n \choose 0}a^nb^0 + {n \choose 1}a^{n-1}b^1 + \cdots + {n \choose n-1}ab^{n-1} + {n \choose n}a^0b^n.$$

So we want $a = 2$ and $b = {x \over 3}$. So we are considering the terms $\displaystyle {n \choose 7}a^{n - 7}b^7$ and $\displaystyle {n\choose 8}a^{n-8}b^8.$ So, $${n \choose 7}a^{n - 7}b^7 = {n\choose 8}a^{n-8}b^8$$ $${n! \over 7!(n - 7)!}a^{n-7}b^7 = {n! \over 8!(n-8)!}a^{n-8}b^8$$ $${a^{n-8}a \over 7!(n-7)(n-8)!} = {a^{n-8}b \over 8\times 7!(n-8)!}$$ $${a \over n-7} = {b \over 8}$$ $$n-7 = {8a \over b}$$ $$n = {48 \over x} + 7$$ Can you see where it comes in now?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \left(2+\frac{x}{3}\right)^{n}=\sum_{i=0} ^n {n \choose k}({\frac{x}{3}})^i 2^{n-i}$
Now for $i =7\implies{n \choose 7}({\frac{x}{3}})^7 2^{n-7}$

and for $i =8\implies{n \choose 8}({\frac{x}{3}})^8 2^{n-8}$

now to get the coefficients of $x^8$ & $x^7$ equal.   $\implies$

${n \choose 7}({\frac{1}{3}})^7 2^{n-7}={n \choose 8}({\frac{1}{3}})^8 2^{n-8} \implies \frac{1}{n-7}=\frac{1}{8}* \frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{2} \implies n=55$